# Facebook app fails to get users credentials

Tags: php, heroku, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I am new to programming and I want to develop a Facebook app with the PHP SDK. I'm hosting the app on heroku and I want to get the users login credentials with the following code.

```
<?php 
require 'php-sdk/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook (array(
'appId' => 'appId',
'secret' => 'appsecret'
));
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Facebook PHP </title>
    </head>
<body>

    <?php 
    $user = $facebook -> getUser();
    if($user)
        echo 'User ID:' , $user , '</p>';
    else:  
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
       echo '<p><a href="' , $loginUrl, '">login</a></p>';
     endif;
    ?>
```

However I get 500 (Internal Server Error) on 'CanvasIFrameLoader' line. Am I missing something?

```
d('CanvasIFrameLoader',['XdArbiterBuffer','Banzai','$'],(function a(b,c,d,e,f,g){c('XdArbiterBuffer');var h={loadFromForm:function j(k,l,m){var n=c('$')('iframe_canvas');if(l&&!i()){l.style.display='block';n.style.display='none';return;}var o=Date.now();n.onload=function(){var p=Date.now(),q=p-o;c('Banzai').post('canvas_iframe_load',{app_id:m,iframe_time_to_load:q});};k.submit();}};function i(){try{var j=document.createElement('canvas');return Boolean(window.WebGLRenderingContext)&&Boolean(j.getContext('webgl')||j.getContext('experimental-webgl'));}catch(k){return false;}}f.exports=h;}),null);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can't see any javascript here, could you paste it ?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mean to say JavaScript. I posted the line on which the error appears to be on.

Comment: That looks like you are using v3 of the PHP SDK, which is more than outdated. I strongly recommend you start with the current version, v5.

Comment: okay thank you! I will look up a new tutorial. It appears that the course I'm following is outdated.

Comment: That last line of code you have shown is clearly JavaScript, not PHP. Absolutely unclear what the connection to the problem is supposed to be here.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted has some basic examples for the current SDK version.